# Triggering a DB call on browser leaving current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I've got an application that I intend to set a lock flag in my database that would exclude others from viewing that same page if set.

However, once set - I have no idea how to "unset" it. I could make it up to the user to unset the flag, but that seems unnecessary.

I'd want to simply look for the browser to leave the page, make a call to the database, and unlock the page.

How does one do this "type" (not looking for the exact way) of thing with JSF/Javascript/jQuery (all options)

Comment: Is this because you don't want people overwriting each other? A more reliable solution might be to have a "last updated" field in the db, and pass that to the client with the data. When the user saves, if the "last updated" is newer than when the data was retrieved, notify the user that someone else has made changes. Perhaps you can give the option to overwrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really not a reliable way to do this, that I've seen anyway.

You can use the browser's `onbeforeunload` event to tell the server, "Hey I'm leaving the page now.".  The issue is you can't actually *block* the page from unloading.  If the user is actually closing the browser, any open sockets are going to be closed immediately.  Your web server may or may not get the request in time.  I've had very flaky results with this approach.

One approach that might work is to employ some sort of *timeout* mechanism.  The page would ping the server every 30 seconds or what not, saying "I'm still here."  If the server did not get this update after a few minutes, it would invalidate the session and free up that document.  Perhaps this could be optimized by checking for the last ping when someone new came along.  One issue with this is if someone left the page, the next user might have to wait a minute or two before they could go to the page.  You'd then have to find a ping frequency that doesn't flood your server with traffic, but also doesn't make the next user have to wait too long.

It's also possible to combine these two methods.  When the user leaves the page, trap the `onbeforeunload` event and immediately invalidate the session.  However, if it didn't work, the session would time out after a minute of not being pinged.

**Are there better solutions?**

If you really need to *lock* a document in a web app so multiple users can't edit it, you might want to investigate your overall design.  Are you afraid of users clobbering data?  If so, maybe employ a mechanism that can resolve merge conflicts, or detect if both sets of changes can be combined.

If you wanted to go truly Web 2.0, you could design something similar to Google Docs, where changes appear live as they're made.  No need for a *Save* button anywhere!

Comment: The timeout solution is the route we are going. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Sending a "keep-alive signal" might be an option. Something along these lines on the frontend side, combined with session cookies.

```
setInterval(function() {
  var img = new Image();
  var src = "http://examle.com/keepalive.gif?cachebuster=" + 
      Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10000 );
}, 1000);
```